# Don't understand why the first variable in a piecewise regression spans all the domain

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, piecewise-linear, segmented-regression

Let us consider one predictor $X \in [a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and one response $Y \in \mathbb{R}$. I need to perform a piecewise linear regression:

$$
Y \sim \beta_0 + \beta_{1,1} X + \beta_{1,2} (X - x^\ast)\cdot\chi[X,x^\ast]
$$

Where:

$$
\chi[x,x^\ast] = 
\begin{cases}
    0       & \quad \text{if } x < x^\ast \\
    1  & \quad \text{if } x \geq x^\ast
  \end{cases}
$$

As you can see, I want to split the regression line for $X$ into two parts determined by knot $x^\ast \in ]a,b[$.
I have my dataset where my predictors and my response are tracked.

#### Question

This is the way piecewise linear regression is performed and I do not understand one thing. In the formula, you can clearly see that we basically have a linear regression on two variables: $X$ and $(X - x^\ast)\cdot\chi[X,x^\ast]$. The latter would make the regression line change from $x^\ast$ to $b$, however the former ($X$) creates a regression line which is fit on all the values $[a,b]$!

Because of this, the first part of the segmented line, will not fit very well the values in $[a,x^\ast]$, while the second part will fit quite well the values in $[x^\ast,b]$. Something like this picture shows (sorry for the bad drawing):

[image]

(In this example, $X^\ast$ is located exactly where the two lines change color as you can probably imageine)

Why do we formulate piecewise regression this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things to think about:

First, segmented regression isn't always formulated the way that you present it. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmented_regression), for example, presents it as two separate regressions above and below the breakpoint.

Second, you can think of the $\beta_{1,2} (X - x^\ast)\cdot\chi[X,x^\ast]$ term as a *correction to* the overall regression equation that spans the entire domain, a correction that only applies above the breakpoint. In your terminology, the slope below the breakpoint would be $\beta_{1,1}$, and that above the breakpoint would be $\beta_{1,1}+\beta_{1,2}$. In your example and formulation of the problem, $\beta_{1,2}$ would be negative. That's still like 2 separate regressions.

Third, the quality of a fit to a segmented regression (or any other modeling approach that uses knots) depends on the choice of location of the knot. What would have happened if you had chosen a breakpoint at a lower $X$ value, say close to the first cluster of points in your display?